# WooCommerce - Ajax Add To Cart and Update Total

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a website that allows users to add products to cart from the home page. I've followed a few resources online from their website and other SO questions which allows me to add products to the cart via Ajax but the cart total will not update without a page reload.

[WooCommerce's documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/show-cart-contents-total/) is where the `cpp_header_add_to_cart_fragment` function came from and it doesn't seem to work at all. Originally I was using `add_to_cart_fragments` but I found out that was deprecated and I should be using `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` but that change doesn't help either.

The more I read the code... I'm noticing that the fragments are being returned from the ajax call so I'm beginning to think I need to replace the html that is showing the cart total with what is returned from the javascript?

**page_home.php**

```
<!-- Cart link to be updated when products are added -->
<a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>">
    <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
</a>
```

**functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cpp_enqueue_scripts');
function cpp_enqueue_scripts() {
    /* Other enqueue/registers */
    wp_register_script('diy_kits', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/diy_kit.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('diy_kits');
    wp_localize_script(
        'diy_kits',
        'cpp_ajax',
        array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'diy_product_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('diy_product_nonce')
        )
    );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cpp_ajax-submit', 'cpp_ajax_submit');
add_action('wp_ajax_cpp_ajax-submit', 'cpp_ajax_submit');
function cpp_ajax_submit() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'diy_product_nonce')) {
        wp_die('Busted!');
    }

    // Add product to cart... this works        
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
    if( $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id ) ) {
        $data = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', array());
        do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);
    } else {
        $data = array( 'success' => false, 'product_id' => $product_id );
    }
    $response = json_encode($data);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo $response; 
    exit;
}
```

**cpp_header_add_to_cart_fragment**

```
// CART UPDATE AJAX this doesn't work
add_filter('woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'cpp_header_add_to_cart_fragment');
function cpp_header_add_to_cart_fragment( $fragments ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    ob_start(); ?>
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>">
        <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
    </a>

    <?php
    $fragments['a.cart-contents'] = ob_get_clean();
    return $fragments;
}
```

**diy_kits.js**

```
// setup and other stuff...
links.click(function(e) {
    /* unrelated stuff */
    jQuery.post(
        cpp_ajax.ajaxurl, 
        {
            action      : 'cpp_ajax-submit',
            nonce       : cpp_ajax.diy_product_nonce,
            product_id  : jQuery(this).attr('data-product-id')
        },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Could I get a comment explaining the downvote? That was almost instant...

Comment: I countered the downvote, although I think your question would benefit from additional description of the occurring problem and the actual-vs-expected results. *I'm struggling with [...]* and *this doesn't work* can be construed as "debug this for me".

Comment: @OhBeWise Thank you. I will edit the question to explain a little more. I do feel like this could be construed as `debug this for me` but the only reason is I've exhausted my knowledge of the subject and can't see any reason why this isn't working.

Comment: @OhBeWise well new I feel stupid... in editing the answer per your request I managed to find the (quite obvious) answer. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Ha, I've had that happen - even poured over problems for hours just to find I changed something unintentionally.  Glad you found it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case someone happens upon this... `woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments` was returning the new html string in the $fragments array and since I was calling it in my ajax function that was being turned into a json object. So in my `diy_kit.js` in the success part of the jquery function, I just had to use that string to update the cart total. I'll paste the edits below:

**page_home.php**

```
<div id="cart_container">
    <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'View your shopping cart' ); ?>">
        <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_total(); ?>
    </a> 
</div>
```

**diy_kit.js**

```
/*inside jQuery.post() function */
function(response) {
    jQuery('#cart_container').html(response['a.cart-contents']);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', function($fragments) {

    ob_start();
    ?>

    <li class="my_cart"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="sidebarCollapse" class="carticonmain"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">          
          <symbol id="shopping-cart" viewBox="0 0 700 700"><title>shopping-cart</title>
              <path d="m150.355469 322.332031c-30.046875 0-54.402344 24.355469-54.402344 54.402344 0 30.042969 24.355469 54.398437 54.402344 54.398437 30.042969 0 54.398437-24.355468 54.398437-54.398437-.03125-30.03125-24.367187-54.371094-54.398437-54.402344zm0 88.800781c-19 0-34.402344-15.402343-34.402344-34.398437 0-19 15.402344-34.402344 34.402344-34.402344 18.996093 0 34.398437 15.402344 34.398437 34.402344 0 18.996094-15.402344 34.398437-34.398437 34.398437zm0 0"></path>
                <path d="m446.855469 94.035156h-353.101563l-7.199218-40.300781c-4.4375-24.808594-23.882813-44.214844-48.699219-48.601563l-26.101563-4.597656c-5.441406-.96875-10.632812 2.660156-11.601562 8.097656-.964844 5.441407 2.660156 10.632813 8.101562 11.601563l26.199219 4.597656c16.53125 2.929688 29.472656 15.871094 32.402344 32.402344l35.398437 199.699219c4.179688 23.894531 24.941406 41.324218 49.199219 41.300781h210c22.0625.066406 41.546875-14.375 47.902344-35.5l47-155.800781c.871093-3.039063.320312-6.3125-1.5-8.898438-1.902344-2.503906-4.859375-3.980468-8-4zm-56.601563 162.796875c-3.773437 12.6875-15.464844 21.367188-28.699218 21.300781h-210c-14.566407.039063-27.035157-10.441406-29.5-24.800781l-24.699219-139.398437h336.097656zm0 0"></path>
                <path d="m360.355469 322.332031c-30.046875 0-54.402344 24.355469-54.402344 54.402344 0 30.042969 24.355469 54.398437 54.402344 54.398437 30.042969 0 54.398437-24.355468 54.398437-54.398437-.03125-30.03125-24.367187-54.371094-54.398437-54.402344zm0 88.800781c-19 0-34.402344-15.402343-34.402344-34.398437 0-19 15.402344-34.402344 34.402344-34.402344 18.996093 0 34.398437 15.402344 34.398437 34.402344 0 18.996094-15.402344 34.398437-34.398437 34.398437zm0 0"></path>
             </symbol> 
        </svg><svg class="icon" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><use xlink:href="#shopping-cart" x="12%" y="16%"></use></svg><i class="item_number">
        <?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>
    </i></a></li>

    <?php $fragments['li.my_cart'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;

} );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', function($fragments) {

    ob_start();
    ?>

    
        <?php woocommerce_mini_cart(); ?>
    

    <?php $fragments['div.minicart_all_data'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;

} );
```